# Request to reopen question 385613

Tags: support, reopen-request

The question https://superuser.com/questions/385613/do-consumer-routers-with-deep-packet-inspection-for-http-traffic-exist has been updated to no longer be a shopping question. I have a solution to his issue using a replacement firmware.

I tried to flag the question to be reopened but it was denied twice. I am posting here on the [recommendation of slhck](https://superuser.com/questions/385613/do-consumer-routers-with-deep-packet-inspection-for-http-traffic-exist#comment434732_385613).

Also what did I do wrong in my flagging to be declined. I understand the first one, it was a typo, but the second one was much more fleshed out and I do not see why it was declined also.

> With the editing that has been done this question is no longer off topic for SO. – 1 hour ago
>
> **declined** - off topic for SO as they don't do non-programming questions, off topic for networks as we don't do shopping questions & what do I buy questions
>
> My previous flag was declined as I made a typo and did SO instead of SU (no way to edit a flag). I agree in the original form the question was closed for the correct reasons, however the question is now on topic after being edited as it is no longer a shopping suggestion, it is a "Does this tech exist?" question which has a definitive yes or no answer, the answer being "Yes with alternative firmware, and this is how you do it...". – 51 mins ago
>
> **declined** - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Answer (score -1):

To have that question no longer be shopping you'd need to edit it so that it's clear that they're trying to do the deep packet inspection with the router they currently have. Not that they want to look for something else and for people to throw in their recommendations or if there's a better product out there.

If they're trying something with what they have and failing, they could be open to suggestions and alternatives.

That would be a more constructive version of the question than currently sits.

Comment: Have you read the most recent edit? That is exactly what it says. _Are there consumer routers **or replacement firmware** available that can perform deep packet inspection_. And if the question was unlocked I would post a more detailed version of what I posted in the comments [in reply](http://superuser.com/questions/385613/do-consumer-routers-with-deep-packet-inspection-for-http-traffic-exist#comment434720_385613) to slhck of where to get the replacement firmware and point to a tutorial of how to get the logging of the level he wants turned on.

Comment: And the edit still leaves it as "I have this router. I want another one instead that does something else"

Comment: I feel that the edit leaves it as "I have this router. It does not do what I want, can I make it do what I want with other firmware or will I need to get a new one, and if I get a new one will it be in the consumer price range?" But I don't care anymore. I posted a link to a tutorial on how to set up what he wants using his existing hardware in the comments so at least cyperpine will be able to use that.